# Python 3.5, Finding user inputted values in a set and displaying them

Tags: python, if-statement, input, set, counter

```
from collections import Counter

inp = input("Please enter some text: ")
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")

if inp in vowels:
    res = Counter(c for c in inp if c in vowels)
    print (res.most_common())

elif inp not in vowels:
    print("No vowels entered.")
```

Code is meant to output vowels if any are found in the users input or if there are none, print a message. Currently the code does not work if more than one vowel in inputted by the user as it print the line "No vowels entered". How can this fault be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` block will only execute if `inp` is a substring of vowels. In order to check for shared characters, like vowels in this case, you can use `any`:

```
if any(i in vowels for i in inp):
    ...
```

Or a set intersection:

```
if vowels.intersection(inp):
    ...
```

You can also simply build build the `Counter` object first, and then test if it's empty to avoid iterating on the input twice:

```
res = Counter(c for c in inp if c in vowels)
if res:
     print(res.most_common(2)) # specify a parameter to avoid printing everything
else:
     print("No vowels entered.")
```

Comment: I came up with exact same line change :) just a tad too late

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That happens :)

Comment: not complaining. Today was full of good questions & upvoted answers :)